# Question on Hom set for fields in the context of universal coefficient theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-homomorphism

My question may be a stupid one or is more about the way of writing things, but I cannot find the answer right now, by myself or via the internet.

I encountered this problem in the context of the Universal coefficient theorem for field-valued relative cohomology. Indeed from the fact that it is field-valued, we have the isomorphism:
\begin{equation}
H^k(\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N}; \mathbb{Z}_2) \simeq \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}\left( H_k(\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N}; \mathbb{Z}_2), \mathbb{Z}_2 \right)
\end{equation}
Now, what happens if $H_k(\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N}; \mathbb{Z}_2) = 0$? The $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(-,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ functor should act on $\mathbb{Z}_2$-valued objects, but for me, $0$ is not such an object... Or maybe I am missing something obvious?

Maybe we write $0$ instead of $0\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, and in that case $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(0\times \mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: The trivial group has a unique structure of $R$-module for any ring $R$, in particular for $R=\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thank you for the comment. Does this mean that my conclusion that $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(0, \mathbb{Z}_2) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$ is correct?

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux No. There's only one homomorphism $0\to M$ for any module $M$, namely: the zero morphism $x\mapsto 0$. And so $\text{Hom}(0,M)\simeq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(-,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ functor should act on $\mathbb{Z}_2$-valued objects, but for me, $0$ is not such an object...

Why not? In fact given any ring $R$, we have the unique (up to isomorphism) zero $R$-module, defined as

$$0=\{\theta\}$$
$$\theta + \theta := \theta$$
$$r\cdot\theta:=\theta\text{ for any }r\in R$$

Not that we have much choice for the addition and scalar multiplication.

And then $\text{Hom}_R(0, M)\simeq 0$ for any $R$-module $M$.